# Wordpress Placing of the_content() function in custom page

Tags: wordpress, custom-pages

I have made a custom page in my wordpress theme. The page is working fine. But I am facing trouble using the_content(); function. I am using a few custom fields to display some content on the page and I want the content of the page, that is entered in the Editor, to be displayed on a specific place on the page. But Whatever I enter in the Editor, gets placed at the top of the page above all other content.

EDIT:

Here is the full code:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
 <div id="main-content">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="mobile-top">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <p><?php the_title(); ?> price</p>
        </a>
        </div>
        <?php comments_template(); ?>
      </div>
</div> <!--main-content Ends-->
```

Comment: Where is your real code for the template ?

Comment: I don't see any custom fields in your code? `the_content()` is currently the only thing in your loop.

Comment: It is an unfinished page. i'm using custom fields later on. How ever this code outputs '<?php the_content(); ?>' two times. Once at the top of everything and once at the position at which it is placed in the above code.